# Convert class to functional component using hooks equivalent to shouldComponentUpdate and componentDidUpdate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to hooks and I came across this example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/iamhosseindhv/notistack/tree/master/examples/redux-example which is a class component and I am trying to convert it to a functional with hooks. I can perfectly use it as it is but the reason is because I want to learn as well.

I tried to implement it with useEffect but I didnt had the desire effect as I still show only one time the notification and if I tried to create again a todo for example it didnt show up.

```
function Notifier(props) {
  const { notifications, removeSnackbar } = props;
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  const [displayed, setDisplayed] = useState([]);

function storeDisplayed(key) {
  setDisplayed([...displayed, key]);
}

console.log(displayed)

notifications.forEach((notification) => {
  setTimeout(() => {

  // If notification already displayed, abort
  if (displayed.indexOf(notification.key) >= 0) return;

  // Display notification using notistack
  enqueueSnackbar(notification.message, notification.options);

  // Add notification's key to the local state
  storeDisplayed(notification.key);

  // Dispatch action to remove the notification from the redux store
  removeSnackbar(notification.key);

 }, 1);
 });

return null;
}
```

I want to display a notification whenever I create or edit something.

Answer (score 0):

Add dependancies array as second parameter to the useeffect

```
useEffect(() => {
//something
  };
}, [props.friend.id]); // Only re-subscribe if props.friend.id changes
```

Comment: I just did it but still same thing, also I notice that the displayed is always undefined

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my implementation is the missing - undefined key, so what I did was to add the key in the redux store and pass it to the component props.

```
function Notifier(props) {
 const { notifications, removeSnackbar } = props;
 const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
 const [displayed, setDisplayed] = useState([]);

function storeDisplayed(key) {
 setDisplayed([...displayed, key]);
}

notifications.forEach((notification) => {
 setTimeout(() => {

 // If notification already displayed, abort
if (displayed.indexOf(notification.options.key) >= 0) return;

// Display notification using notistack
enqueueSnackbar(notification.message, notification.options);

// Add notification's key to the local state
storeDisplayed(notification.options.key);

// Dispatch action to remove the notification from the redux store
removeSnackbar(notification.options.key);

 }, 1);
});

return null;
}
```